# Too many values to unpack in pytube module problem

Tags: python, python-py

Monday 27 jul 2020, I'm running pytube module perfectly but after one day later its code is not working any more. It's show's **too many values to unpack (expected 2)**

```
from pytube import YouTube
url = input ("Entry url : ")
yt = YouTube(url)
captions = yt.captions.get_by_language_code('en')
all = captions.generate_srt_captions()
print(all)
```

Anyone know this ? Or other modules like this to extract YouTube captions ?

Comment: There is a bug filed - https://github.com/nficano/pytube/issues/695

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Here`](https://github.com/nficano/pytube/pull/701) is the solution.

In the file: `pytube/cipher.py`, instead of:

```py
r'\b(?P<sig>[a-zA-Z0-9$]{2})\s*=\s*function\(\s*a\s*\)\s*{\s*a\s*=\s*a\.split\(\s*""\s*\)'
```

use:

```py
r'(?:\b|[^a-zA-Z0-9$])(?P<sig>[a-zA-Z0-9$]{2})\s*=\s*function\(\s*a\s*\)\s*{\s*a\s*=\s*a\.split\(\s*""\s*\)'
```